# PostgreSQL and hstore in order to make two key value stores

Tags: sql, postgresql, hstore

I would like to create two key value stores. One that has a key of a url and a value of a url and the other has a url (this is the value of the other tables) and a score (integer).

I've tried to read the [hstore documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) but I cant really find how to create the tables.

I want to represent the urls as strings. I am mapping a url to its "parent url". The idea of a score should be more like an index the higher the index the better the website (calculated based with the idea of connectivity to other pages and time to access). Basically some sample data might look like this:

```
key url:    https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl
parent url: https://www.google.com/

parent url: https://www.google.com/
score: 100

key url: http://www.cracked.com/blog/5-things-you-should-know-before-making-indie-movie/
parent url: http://www.cracked.com/

parent url: http://www.cracked.com/
score: 125
```

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more detail for it to be practical to help you. Right now you haven't described anything you can't do with a pair of ordinary non-hstore columns. Try describing your data and its relationships in more detail. Add some sample data showing how it's supposed to fit together. What's the key - where does it come from, what kind of data is it? Is there more than one score per URL?

Comment: I've tried to provide more information above thanks in advance for the help. I guess a better question is if this is what im trying to do is there a reason to use hstore instead of a simple table with an index

Comment: I can't see why `hstore` applies here. It seems like an ordinary 1:many relationship you could model with an ordinary pair of tables and a foreign key. While you could add a `hstore` column to store the individual URLs, doing so would be very inefficient as you'd have to rewrite the whole `hstore` whenever any element changes.

Comment: it would rewrite anytime an element is modified or anytime another entry is inserted into the table

Comment: `hstore` is just a value, like `text` or `integer`. If you change *any part* of the `hstore`, or any other column in the row containing the `hstore`, the whole hstore must be copied into a new row version. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc.html

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any reason you'd want to use `hstore` here.

You could model this with a simple pair of tables. Here's a simple translation of your data:

```
CREATE TABLE url_scores(
    parent_url text primary key,
    score integer not null
);

CREATE TABLE url_mappings(
    key_url text not null,
    parent_url text not null references url_scores(parent_url)
);

INSERT INTO url_scores(parent_url, score) VALUES ('https://www.google.com/', 100);
INSERT INTO url_scores(parent_url, score) VALUES ('http://www.cracked.com/', 125);

INSERT INTO url_mappings(key_url, parent_url)
VALUES ('https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl', 'https://www.google.com/');

INSERT INTO url_mappings(key_url, parent_url)
VALUES ('http://www.cracked.com/blog/5-things-you-should-know-before-making-indie-movie/
', 'http://www.cracked.com/');
```

... however, you're likely to want to normalize it some more, splitting http/https and the domain out into parts, possibly using a surrogate key into `url_scores` instead of storing `parent_url` twice, etc.

It's entirely possible that a relational DB isn't the right storage for your data, by the way. It's hard to say without knowing what you're doing with it.

Anyway, read the PostgreSQL tutorial and some general information on database design.